# $(document).ready(function(){}); fails on IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm using a single js file for multiple php pages. At the end of each php I create a javascript variable to identify it, like this:

```
<div>    
.
.
.
</div>

<script>
var idp = 1;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in my js file I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    .
    .
    .
    if (idp == 1) {
       FunctionWithTheCodeForPage1();
    }
    if (idp == 2) {
       FunctionWithTheCodeForPage2();
    }
});
```

It works fine on Chrome and on Firefox but in IE9 sometimes it does not seems to get the value of idp variable and sometimes it does not execute some jquery code I have before the "if" statements, seems like the problem is the $(document).ready(); because I have set the FunctionWithTheCodeForPage1(); directly inside the php for page 1 and it works, but the rest of the code inside $(document).ready(); does not.

This are the libreries I'm using:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/Popcalendar.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/jquery-latest.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/jquery.lightbox_me.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/MyJS.js'></script>
```

This problem does not happens all the time, sometimes the page loads right and sometimes gets this error, but mostly with the error. 
Are there compatibility problems with IE9? What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: What version is `jquery-latest`? There was a bug in 1.8.0 with respect to this.

Comment: Can you show us how you're actually loading all of these scripts in a single code example, ideally on jsfiddle, without breaking it up into multiple chunks? I think you have an asynchrony issue, not an IE9 issue - it just happens to be screwing up in IE9 for now.

Comment: I was using 1.8.0, I just updated to 1.8.1 and made the changes suggested by Tomalak and apparently it got fixed, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have several functions ready, just pass them directly to jQuery instead of taking a detour over some ID variable.

If you pass a function to jQuery, it will be executed as soon as the page is ready. Normally this is done using an anonymous function, like this:

```
$(function() {   // or $(document).ready(function() {
  // ...
});
```

but you can also just pass an existing function that you defined earlier.

```
$(FunctionWithTheCodeForPage1);
```

You can also define a unique ID for the bodies and have a single function:

```
$(function () {
  $("body#page1").each(function () {
    // page1 specific;
  });
  $("body#page2").each(function () {
    // page2 specific;
  });
});
```

This way you would not have to add *any* extra script to your pages.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the jquery version to 1.8.1 and I fixed it this way and seems that it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, where `$(document).ready(function() {...}` wasn't being invoked by IE9.

It turned out IE9 was working in "Quirks" mode. (Use the F12 menu to find out more info).

I simply added the following (html5 doctype) to the top of the page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And the following header...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

And IE9 started playing nicely! Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing.

Set that `var idp` value using php rather hardcoding it. IT will make sure to populate it.

Note:

You can also populate a hidden field using php and take the value of it.

Comment: So hardcoding does not make sure it is populated?

Comment: hardcoding make sure its populated but it does not make sure when it is populated whether some script before it trying to access the value of it before that variable is in dom or not. But when some varialble is runat  server it will render first then only client side scripts will run.

Comment: In the end you will end up with the same output from the server, and the OP's problem still occurs.